# XmlDocument to read XML file, passed as SOAP message body

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, xmldocument

I am using XmlDocument to read an XML document's contents and then pass those contents along in the SOAP message body of a web service request. However, in the data that is actually getting passed along in the call (that was read from the XML document) the < and > symbols are being replaced with

```
&gt; and &lt;
```

which is causing issues on the receiving end.

What am I missing?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
string filePath = FileList.SelectedItem.Value;
string doc = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = true };
xDoc.LoadXml(doc);


MyService.TransactionRequest request = new MyService.TransactionRequest { message = xDoc.OuterXml };


MyService.TransactionClient client = new MyService.TransactionClient();


client.ProcessTransaction(request);
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to wrap the contents of the message in a CDATA construct, which should (knock on wood) prevent the SOAP message encoder from transforming the XML tags in your string.

```
string wrapped = "<![CDATA[" + xDoc.OuterXml + "]]>";
TransactionRequest request = new MyService.TransactionRequest { message = wrapped };
```

If your xDoc may contain CDATA sections itself, then you need to do a little more work, because CDATA sections cannot be nested.  There is an easy workaround, though.  Just replace all occurences of `"]]>"` with `"]]]]><![CDATA[>"` in the string to be wrapped.

```
string toWrap = xDoc.OuterXml.Replace("]]>", "]]]]><![CDATA[>");
string wrapped = "<![CDATA[" + toWrap + "]]>";
TransactionRequest request = new MyService.TransactionRequest { message = wrapped };
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA.